# How to do base class concept for CRUD in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Currently Am doing student project in angularJS. In that I need to use base class concept 
for CRUD operation.. I need to create one base class in that class contain 
Create, read, update and delete method.. through out the application I need use the common method based on the parameter and object save the data corresponding location..

Comment: You can make use of service or factory. for you application create one common factory and pass required parameter to that factory and declare all CRUD methods which in turns call backend API methods in that factory.

after that you need to just inject it into your controller.

Comment: can u share any live example  @Amit Ramoliya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service or factory to handle all your `$http` needs. Using angular's `$http` [shortcut methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for `post`, `get`, `put` and `delete` which returns a promise

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
  var create = function() {
    return $http.post("/api/...") // returns a promise
  };

  var read = function() {
    return $http.get("/api/...") 
  };

  var update = function() {
    return $http.put("/api/...") 
  };

  var delete = function() {
    return $http.delete("/api/...") 
  };

  return {
    create: create,
    read: read,
    update: update,
    delete: delete
  }
});
```

This can be re-used throughout your application like this:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, DataService){
  DataService.read().then(
    function(data){
      console.log(data)
    },
    function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
});
```

Comment: In that function id, url and object if I pass its works dynamically correct? @sjokkogutten

Comment: So I can use the same service for CRUD operation through out the application right? @sjokkogutten

Comment: Yes, you'll need to implement url and parameters: `$http.post('/someUrl', data, config)`. It is all described in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Yes, you can use this service throughout the application. Just remember to inject DataService when you need to use it,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `service` or `factory` that contains only your `CRUD` functions and you can inject that `service` in your `controller` and pass `arguments` or `object` to the specific service function.

**Updated to show Example:**

```
app.factory('baseService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        return {
            create: function(data) {
              return $http.post('/api/..', data);
            },
            read: function() {
                return $http.get('/api/..');
            },
            update: function() {
                return $http.put('/api/..', data);
            },
            delete: function() {
                return $http.delete('/api/..');
            }
        };
    }
]);

app.controller('yourController', ['$scope', 'baseService',
    function($scope, baseService) {
        baseService.read().then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
]);
```

Comment: can u share any live example @shaishab roy

Comment: Added an example @Suresh B . you can try it if will need